# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 VM on Windows 7

Tags: vmware, software-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 as a VM guest, Windows 7 host (tried installing Ubuntu 13 before that, as a guest as well, but got the same problem) on VMware. My problem is that I end up on a terminal that tells me:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS(GNU/Linux 3.5.0-23-generic i686)

*Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

167 packages can be updated.
82 updates are security updates.
```

[image: VMware Screenshot]

Is this normal? Could anyone tell me what to type afterwards?

Comment: Are you on 12.04, or 13.04 now?

Comment: I'm on 12.04 right now !

Comment: Can you upload an image to a website, and give me the link, so I can add it for you?

Comment: Here it is, on my twitter account. https://twitter.com/ThomCunning Thanks for your time and involvement!

Comment: Well, I never - that startx did it. Thanks so much Mitch !

Answer (score 1):

You're typing

`apt=get install`

Instead of

`apt-get install`

The first one sets an environment variable called `apt` to the value `get`, and then runs the `install` program, which is a much lower level utility used when compiling your own software (which most people do not do).

The second one runs the utility apt-get, which is a command line interface to the package manager.

---

And for `su` ; `su` elevates you to the super user, but you need to know the super user's password... alas, on Ubuntu, `root` (the super user) has no password. This is what `sudo` is for - `sudo` lets you pretend to be the super user, and needs *your* password, not the password for root.

Happily, you can run `su` while pretending to be the super user...

`sudo su`

And feed it your user password, not the password for root.

Answer (score 0):

Well to get started, just type `startx` at the prompt, and that should do it.

startx will start the GUI that will allow you running a single session of the X Window System.